# How to setup cron job in Magento 2 to reindex indexers

Tags: magento-2.1

Please provide me a solution with a code.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/magento-2-cron-job/).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ubuntu you can open configured cron jobs by using command `crontab -e` .

Now let's say you want to run indexer every minute, you can configure it like this

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
*/01 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: This is not the solution. Why would you reindex everything every minute, negating the benefits of the indexes? See Akhilesh comment with link to Magento docs on how to set it up.

Comment: This was just an example as mentioned in the answer. Of course you have to keep it's impact in mind and set time accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a whole section in the magento develop docs which discuss how to go about setting up the cron and the different scenarios

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

The only difference is that you would use `php bin/magento index:reindex`

If you are still stuck you could reach out to your host. If you get someone good they might help you out with what do do that's specific to who you are using.